# Spawned Process starting but not running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5

So i am attempting to start an instance of Teracopy or Robocopy to copy files from one location to another after the user clicks a button on an deployed ASP.net webpage running on IIS7.5

This works fine on my debug system, but when running it on the deployed server the process opens but never does anything?

[image]

The task will stay there forever until i kill it, and i have no way of seeing the window as its opened by Network Service so i am not sure if there is a reason its not doing anything...

If i click the button multiple instances open up and do nothing.  I've tried running the process as another account but then the process doesnt even start.

The same thing happens if i use Robocopy

Comment: Does `NETWORK SERVICE` have the correct permissions to run this process and copy files from one location to another on your production machine?

Comment: Have you tried to capture the `StandardOutput` or `StandardError` streams to a log file (or other logging mechanism) to capture and details from the appplication?

Comment: Yes the NETWORK SERVICE should have the proper permissions.  Whats annoying is that i have another page on this same website that runs another exe perfectly fine with no issues, opens the file, creates a pdf, saves it to the remote server.  This page though i cant even get to run any exe that does nothing but copy files around within the Websites home directory...  I did try outputting StandardOutput to a file but nothing ever got written.  In the end all i need is a method of copying files out of one directory to another in a non blocking fashion.